# Kivy - Updating label in kv code from python side

Tags: python, sqlite, user-interface, kivy

I'm trying to make a GUI with a few screens and a button that will fetch some data from an SQLite database and assign that to a label to be displayed on the GUI screen. I'm still new to kivy, python, and object-oriented programming in general. I try to run this, and it seems to work fine for fetching the SQL data but I'm having trouble assigning it to the label I want displayed. The error I get is "attribute error: 'float' object has no attribute 'psarjvalue'", so I understand that it's looking in my float layout and trying to find psarjvalue but is not succeeding, why not? I also tried assigning an id to the float layout but I'm clearly missing something.

```py
import kivy
import sqlite3
import sched, time
import smbus
import time
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js
import os
import signal
import multiprocessing, signal
from kivy.uix.behaviors.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition, WipeTransition, SwapTransition

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x04 

psarj = 0.00

p = multiprocessing.Process(target = muterun_js,args=('iss_telemetry.js',))

conn = sqlite3.connect('iss_telemetry.db')
c = conn.cursor()

class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class CalibrateScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ManualControlScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ManualControlScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MimicScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MimicScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def updatePSARJ(self, *args, **kwargs):
        c.execute('SELECT two FROM telemetry where one="psarj"') 
        psarj = c.fetchone()
        label = self.psarjvalue
        label.text = psarj

       # self.psarjvalue.text = psarj

class MainScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

#def updatePSARJ(*args):
#    c.execute('SELECT two FROM telemetry where one="psarj"') 
#    psarj = c.fetchone()
#    MimicScreen.psarjlabel.text = psarj

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = ScreenManager(transition=WipeTransition())
        root.add_widget(MainScreen(name = 'main'))
        root.add_widget(CalibrateScreen(name = 'calibrate'))
        root.add_widget(MimicScreen(name = 'mimic'))
        root.add_widget(ManualControlScreen(name = 'manualcontrol'))
        root.current= 'main'
        return root

    def startTelemetry(*kwargs):
        p.start()

    def stopTelemetry(*kwargs):
        os.kill(p.pid,signal.SIGKILL)

#def update_values(*args):
#    c.execute('SELECT two FROM telemetry where one="psarj"') 
#    psarj = c.fetchone()
#    MimicScreen.updatePSARJ()

Clock.schedule_interval(MimicScreen.updatePSARJ, 1)

Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.8
#:import kivy kivy
#:import win kivy.core.window

<MimicScreen>:
    name: 'mimic'
    FloatLayout:
        id: mimicscreenlayout
        Image:
            source: 'iss1.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Label:
            id: psarjvalue
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.5}
            text: '0.003'
            markup: True
            color: 1,1,1
            font_size: 60
        Label:
            id: telemetrystatus
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.6, "center_y": 0.8}
            text: 'Telemetry'
            markup: True
            color: 1,0,1
            font_size: 60
        Button:
            id: mimicstartbutton
            size_hint: 0.3,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.6}
            text: 'MIMIC'
            disabled: False
            font_size: 30
            on_release: telemetrystatus.text = 'Fetching Telemetry...'
            on_release: app.startTelemetry()
            on_release: mimicstopbutton.disabled = False
            on_release: mimicstartbutton.disabled = True
        Button:
            id: mimicstopbutton
            size_hint: 0.3,0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.4}
            text: 'Stop'
            disabled: True
            font_size: 30
            on_release: telemetrystatus.text = 'Program Stopped'
            on_release: app.stopTelemetry()
            on_release: mimicstopbutton.disabled = True
            on_release: mimicstartbutton.disabled = False
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.3,0.1
            pos_hint: {"Left": 1, "Bottom": 1}
            text: 'Return'
            font_size: 30
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'main'

''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

This is the part of the kv code that has the label I want to update:

```py
<MimicScreen>:
    name: 'mimic'
    FloatLayout:
        id: mimicscreenlayout
        Image:
            source: 'iss1.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
        Label:
            id: psarjvalue
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "center_y": 0.5}
            text: '0.003'
            markup: True
            color: 1,1,1
            font_size: 60
```

And this is the relevant part of the python side

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('iss_telemetry.db')
c = conn.cursor()

class MimicScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MimicScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def updatePSARJ(self, *args, **kwargs):
        c.execute('SELECT two FROM telemetry where one="psarj"') 
        psarj = c.fetchone()
        label = self.psarjvalue
        label.text = psarj
```

label = self.psarjvalue is where the problem occurs

How do I link this to my kv label?
I've tried label = self.ids['psarjvalue'] and same error

...something something object properties?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: After seeing the full code, the issues seems to be on the scheduling of the method that updates the labels.

`Clock.schedule_interval(MimicScreen.updatePSARJ, 1)`

I cannot fully test your code due to missing python libs, but perhaps creating a `MainApp` method that will be passed to `Clock.schedule_interval` will achieve the same end. (Comment or remove the original `Clock.schedule_interval(MimicScreen.updatePSARJ, 1)`)

```
MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Create attribute that will be used to reference labels
        self.m_screen = MimicScreen(name = 'mimic')
        root = ScreenManager(transition=WipeTransition())
        root.add_widget(MainScreen(name = 'main'))
        root.add_widget(CalibrateScreen(name = 'calibrate'))
        # Provide the above created attribute instead of creating a new instance
        root.add_widget(self.m_screen)
        root.add_widget(ManualControlScreen(name = 'manualcontrol'))
        root.current= 'main'

        # Put the schedule function here, and reference the new function defined below
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_labels, 1)
        return root

    # This method will periodically update the label text
    def update_labels(self, dt):
        c.execute('SELECT two FROM telemetry where one="psarj"')
        psarj = c.fetchone()
        self.m_screen.ids.psarjvalue.text = psarj

    def startTelemetry(*kwargs):
        p.start()

    def stopTelemetry(*kwargs):
        os.kill(p.pid,signal.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'ids'

Comment: Seeing the full code, the issue seems to be in `Clock.schedule_interval(MimicScreen.updatePSARJ, 1)`. In this way, the `self` attribute becomes the float 1 instead of the Screen object. From what I see you want to schedule a function that updates the label text periodically, yes?

Comment: Correct, I'd like to have a label (several labels actually) on a screen each represent a value from my SQL database (that will be constantly updating) so I'd like each label to update to equal that value about once per second

Comment: YES! Works perfectly!! Thank you so much!